# Help counting total number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following type of query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Table.Table_ID
LIMIT 10
```

I want to know how many rows would be selected if that `LIMIT 10` weren't there.  I can't simply select `COUNT(Table_ID)` because I group by that, so it will give 1 in every row for that.

Comment: Why not just run another query that gets the value you want? Otherwise would you want the total count returned with every row?

Comment: @JohnFx: It's very common for pagination, for example.

Comment: I can understand that. So why not do it in a separate query then?

Comment: @JohnFx: Why would you want to perform a second [potentially large] query on a table just to do a count, when MySQL already has this information available for you?

Comment: @JohnFx: Technically it is a separate query: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` ;)

Comment: @webbiedave: Not on the table, though ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: Was responding to JohnFx (tongue-in-cheek).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly described in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` tells MySQL to calculate how many rows there would
>   be in the result set, disregarding any `LIMIT` clause. The number of
>   rows can then be retrieved with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`. See Section
>   11.13, “Information Functions”.

If you follow the link to Section 11.13, there's then an example:

> `FOUND_ROWS()`
>
> A `SELECT` statement may include a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the `LIMIT`, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the `SELECT` statement, and then invoke `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
>     -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
> mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
> ```
>
> **The second `SELECT` returns a number indicating how many rows the first `SELECT` would have returned had it been written without the `LIMIT` clause.**
>
> In the absence of the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the most recent successful SELECT statement, `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows in the result set returned by that statement. If the statement includes a `LIMIT` clause, `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows up to the limit. For example, `FOUND_ROWS()` returns `10` or `60`, respectively, if the statement includes `LIMIT 10` or `LIMIT 50, 10`.

Please, use the documentation as your first port of call.

Comment: So there is no way to do it in one query?

Comment: @babonk: No. Why is that a requirement?

Comment: It's not a requirement.  Was just asking the question to see if it was possible for simplicity. I guess I don't know MySQL well enough because I'm constantly surprised that you can't do basic things in a single query. Will accept your answer...

Comment: @babonk: OK, cool. :) Don't be too afraid of second queries, especially when they're just internal function calls like this.

Comment: @babonk - You are asking MySQL two questions. Two queries seems like the appropriate number.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_ID) FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score -2):

You could call the [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function on a result set containing all the rows to find out.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY Table.Table_ID');
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: This will return at most 10 (the LIMIT).

Comment: This is the number of rows the query returns which the LIMIT 10 will give incorrect results.

Comment: -1: No; that yields the number of rows in the resultset, i.e. 10.

Comment: Ack. Forgot to take the `LIMIT` clause out.