# What's the best way to count MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search engine on a shared host that uses MySQL. This search engine potentially has millions/trillions etc of records.

Each time a search is performed I return a count of the records that can then be used for pagination purposes.

The count tells you how many results there are in regard to the search performed. MySQL count is I believe considered quite slow.

Order of search queries:

1. Search executed and results returned
2. Count query executed

I don't perform a PHP count as this will be far slower in larger data sets.

Question is, do I need to worry about MySQL "count" and at what stage should I worry about it. How do the big search engines perform this task?

Comment: Trillions? Sadly, you shouldn't worry about the COUNT operation being slow but LIMIT, OFFSET not doing what you expect it'll do - it retrieves the whole dataset and then discards it starting at OFFSET, ending at LIMIT.

Comment: Trillions of records on a shared host? Good luck... You're going to grind that server into the ground.

Comment: See this answer on another question. Your question isn't a duplicate, but the answer over there pretty much covers your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478194/help-counting-total-number-of-rows/7478212#7478212

Comment: Per Marc's comment, you'll want to look at load as your search engine grows. But you've got to start somewhere. Just keep an eye on it as the size can get very large, very, very quickly.

Comment: Trillions? Really? Now, how many rows do you really have and what budget do you have for a real RDBMS and your own hardware...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases the answer is indexing. The larger your database gets the more important it is to have a well designed and optimized indexing strategy.

The importance of indexing on a large database can not be overstated.

You are absolutely right about not looping in code to count DB records. Your RDBMS is optimized for operations like that, your programming language is no. Wherever possible you want to do any sorting, grouping, counting, filtering operations within the SQL language provided by your RDBMS.

As for efficiently getting the count on a "paginated" query that uses a LIMIT clause, check out [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

> SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tells MySQL to calculate how many rows there would
>   be in the result set, disregarding any LIMIT clause. The number of
>   rows can then be retrieved with SELECT FOUND_ROWS(). See Section
>   11.13, “Information Functions”.

Comment: I really don't think that addresses the OP question.

Comment: I'm answering the question as asked "How do the big search engines perform this task?" and the implied question "How to do they do it quickly on really large databases."

Comment: In any event. I added a reference to a row counting technique to cover more of the breadth of his question.

Comment: @JohnFx +1 Yes, this is one of the possible solutions for medium size databases. But on very large databases `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` decreases the performance, because it still needs to count all the rows. I think the best way would be to use some kind of solution based on approximation.

Comment: Many thanks - I am using a LIMIT OFFSET search so this could be very useful I will check out SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Answer (score 2):

If MySQL database reaches several millions of records, that's a sign you'll be forced to stop using monolithic data store - meaning you'll have to split reads, writes and most likely use a different storage engine than the default one.

Once that happens, you'll stop using the actual count of the rows and you'll start using the estimate, cache the search results and so on in order to alleviate the work on the database. Even Google uses caching and displays an estimate of number of records.

Anyway, for now, you've got 2 options:

1 - Run 2 queries, one to retrieve the data and the other one where you use COUNT() to get the number of rows.

2 - Use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS like @JohnFX suggested.

[Percona has an article about what's faster](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/), tho it might be outdated now.

The biggest problem you're facing is [the way MySQL uses LIMIT OFFSET](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/), which means you probably won't like your users using large offset numbers.

In case you indeed get millions of records - I don't forsee a bright future for your MySQL monolithic storage on a shared server. However, good luck to you and your project.

Comment: I was actually using a select * and returning mysql_num_rows, as I believe a select is faster than a count, at least it used to be in postgreSQL a few years back! I'm looking at SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS for the moment. Thanks for the gesture of luck. If all goes well, bye bye shared hosting!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do properly, you can execute the one query, and perform the `mysql_num_rows()` function on the result in PHP... that should be pretty zippy.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: OP is using pagination, so this will not give the desired result.

Comment: @Karolis, you're assuming the methodology the OP is using for pagination is some multi-query, LIMITing methodology.

Comment: OP seems to be using pagination in code, or at least that's the way I understood it.

Comment: If downvoting, please help the answerer by telling him/her why you're downvoting. Maybe the answer can be improved that way. (And once the answer is improved, the downvote should be removed.)

Comment: Once again, someone who doesn't understand what downvoting is supposed to be used for downvotes.  Low class.

Comment: @JonathanM Yes. I think that OP is using LIMIT because post-query solutions would be very slow on large databases.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the reply. I'm looking to limit my data set by doing a LIMIT OFFSET query rather than dealing with a huge dataset and relying on pagination to sort it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using PHP, you could use the `mysql_num_rows` method to tell you the count after the query is done. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: The link you have is wrong.  That's for affected rows, not row count.

Comment: OP is using pagination (most likely with LIMIT clause), so this method will not give what is expected.

Comment: Also it only tells you the number of rows in the data returned, not the total size of the query results (assuming a LIMIT is specified for paging)

Comment: @Karolis: It's possible that may come into play, but if he's doing pagination via some post-query methodology, this solution should work for him.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment on how this answer is not useful? Maybe I can improve it.

Comment: @JohnFx, I'm not making that assumption about his pagination method. There are almost as many pagination methods as there are programmers.

Comment: @Johnatan M - in order to perform the pagination, one has to know how many rows there are in total. mysql_num_rows returns only the number of rows returned by the database, it doesn't mean that's all there is stored in the db since it can be (and probably is) affected by LIMIT clause as mentioned by JohnFX. Therefore, your post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think the problem is that the title question and the question text don't match in what they are asking. I concede that this answers the title question. I just didn't think it answered the question in the body of the OP. I'll undo my downvote if you edit (I can't otherwise)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm currently using a OFFSET LIMIT approach so have gone with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS for the moment as said above mysql_num_rows only returns the number of selected results not the total number of results without the limit.

Comment: You're right the title isn't so hot but it is broadly relevant. Anyway look at all these replies - many thanks for the help.